# Como fazer MySql retornar utf-8?

Tags: mysql

Quando requisito informações do meu banco que contenham caracteres especiais recebo "�" porém no phpmyadmin em agrupamento está "UTF-8" e meu site também tem o meta de UTF-8 o que posso fazer para retornar o correto?

Comment: Utilize `urf8_encode($string)` ou `urf8_decode($string)`

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu desconhecia dessa função

Comment: @MarceloBoni Adiciona como pergunta para que eu marque a resposta pf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uma sugestão é converter tudo que **entra** no banco de dados em entidades html, como segue o código php:

```
$email = addslashes(htmlentities($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
```

Dessa forma, todos os caracteres especiais são convertidos, e na hora de exibi-los, o próprio navegador o interpretará.

Será convertido segundo a tabela disponível em http://erikasarti.net/html/acentuacao-caracteres-especiais/

á = á (&aacute)

ã = ã (&atilde)

e assim por diante

---

**UPDATE**

Outra sugestão que seria mais apropriada é criar um banco de dados na codificação UTF-8. Você poderá criar o banco MySQL já em UTF-8:

```
CREATE DATABASE `banco` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Poderá criar uma tabela em UTF-8

```
CREATE TABLE document (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    campo VARCHAR(50),
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Lembre-se de definir o charset UTF-8 em suas páginas HTML

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

E de utilizar o header UTF-8 nos arquivos PHP

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>
```

Se ainda não for possível cadastrar acentos no banco de dados você poderá utilizar no PHP

```
// Para mysqli
 mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

// Para PDO
 $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=world;charset=utf8";
 $opcoes = array(
     PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8'
 );
 $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $senha, $opcoes);
```

Outra coisa que talvez possa ajudar é adicionando a seu .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Lembre-se, *"nenhum UTF-8 é de mais"*.

Answer (score 6):

Não sei se é o ideal, mas você pode fazer uma consulta dessa forma também

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_produto WHERE nome_produto = :nome_produto collate utf8_unicode_ci ";
```

Answer (score 5):

Se estiver a usar PDO acrescente esta linha:

```
$pdo -> exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

Answer (score 2):

Se estiver usando mysqli, use a função mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8"). Essa função define o conjunto de caracteres default para enviar e receber dados para o Banco de Dados.
Se estiver usando PDO e PHP acima da versão 5.3.6 pode especificar o conjunto de caracteres no DSN.

```
$dsn = sprintf("mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s;charset=utf8", $host, $dbname);
                $connection = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
```

Ou (Para versões do PHP anterior a 5.3.6)

```
$dsn = sprintf("mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s", $this->host, $this->dbname);
                    $connection = new \PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->password);
$connection->exec('SET names = utf-8');
```