# problemas com sinais de uma consulta mysql com php

Tags: php

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputCNPJ">Atividade Primária</label>
        <br />
        <select name="id_cnae" class="browser-default custom-select">
                <option value=0>Atividade Primária</option>
                <?php                                
                        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id_cnae, descricao FROM CNAE") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                        while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) { 
                ?>
                <option value='<?php echo $aux["id_cnae"]?>'><?php echo $aux["descricao"] ?>
                </option>
                <?php
                        }
                ?>
        </select>
</div>
```

Estou com problemas no front, o resultado sai com simbolos ao invés de Ç e acentuação, meu html já tem UTF-8

Comment: Caro Jonas, tem que ajustar a conexão também, a estrutura do banco (talvez já esteja ok) e salvar os seus .php em UTF-8 sem "B O M". Tá detalhado na pergunta que linkei na sua

Answer (score -2):

Adicione `<meta charset='utf-8'>` ao `header` do seu arquivo HTML.

OU

Tente alterar sua `query` para `SELECT id_cnae, descricao FROM CNAE collate utf8_unicode_ci`.
Mas sugiro que você troque a collação (se é assim que chama) das suas tabelas no banco.

Fonte: [Outra pergunta do Sopt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/229281/como-fazer-mysql-retornar-utf-8)

Comment: já adicionei, mas não funcionou